# Headers and pages in groovy

Tags: groovy, header, report

I'm converting a report written in SQR (old stuff) into groovy.  SQR has a class that will allow you to specify a line-count, such that after that many lines of text are written to the report it will re-print the report header for you (as well as the page number that it keeps track of for you) so that when you go to the next page, the header is at the top of that page rather than a page or two back.  Does groovy have anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Groovy itself is a generic language and not one for writing reports, the short answer is **no**.

You could try to find some java libraries that do what you want or at least support you. There are many many java libraries out there and Groovy is one of the JVM based languages that integrate really well with java lib. Maybe this SO answer is a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942247/i-need-some-java-reporting-engine

Also, be a bit more specific in your question. What is the target format for the report? Word, PDF or something else? What is a page in your case? etc...

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Right now we're just putting out text files, though we may look at PDF files in the future.  We're not serving anything on an application server though we are not opposed to that (ie, html output and the like).  In other words, there's some flexibility and we're open to exploring different options.  I'm trying to leave my question generic so that I can compare a variety of options if possible.  I started looking at JasperReports, the seemingly defacto standard right now, but it doesn't look like it would handle the complexity that I'm talking about in my question.